# Display list of trails in React - "Warning: Failed prop type"

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, runtime-error

React Newbie

I am coding in React. I am taking an object of JSON data from a GET request to an api, and trying to pass it as a prop in a component. Then I am mapping over it to make a list of "trail" objects.

I am getting this error in the console:
*"Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `trail` of type `array` supplied to `TrailItem`, expected `object`."*

Here's the code for my app level component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Navbar from "./components/layout/Navbar";
import Trails from "./components/trails/Trails";
import axios from "axios";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    trails: {},
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const res = await axios.get(
      `https://www.hikingproject.com/data/get-trails?lat=35.0844&lon=-106.6504&maxDistance=10&key=${process.env.REACT_APP_HIKING_PROJECT_KEY}`
    );

    console.log(res.data);

    this.setState({ trails: res.data });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <Navbar />
        <div>
          <Trails trails={this.state.trails} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

As far as I can tell, there is no problem with the data. A `console.log(res.data);` returns an object, so I know the api request is working.

Here's the code for my "Trails" component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import TrailItem from "./TrailItem";

class Trails extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={trailStyle}>
        {Object.keys(this.props.trails).map((key) => (
          <TrailItem key={key} trail={this.props.trails[key]} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const trailStyle = {
  display: "grid",
  gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(3, 1fr)",
  gridGap: "1rem",
};

export default Trails;
```

I feel like maybe I'm not using the correct syntax to step into the object, and then further into the "trails" array, but I'm stumped. Thank you for you help!

*EDIT*
Here is the "TrailItem" code:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const TrailItem = ({ trail: { name, location, imgSmall } }) => {
  return (
    <div className='card text-center'>
      <img src={imgSmall} alt='trail' style={{ width: "25%" }} />
      <h3>{name}</h3>
      <p>{location}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

TrailItem.propTypes = {
  trail: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};

export default TrailItem;
```

I followed the advice of one of the comments and changed the PropType to array, and that fixed one of the warnings. But I still can't get a list of `<TrailItem />`.

Comment: `this.props.trails[key]` is an array, but you have seemingly marked it as an object in `TrailItem` prop types

Comment: you checked the API response in console, but u need to check what data you are passing to TrailItems, so if you console or debugged in that point, you get to know what exactly issue is

Comment: @Agney Object properties can be accessed the same way as array indices, after all, JS objects are just associative arrays of key-value pairs. I.E. `foo = { bar: 'bang' }` then `foo['bar']` yields `'bang'`. Now, if this is what the OP means is a whole different story.

Comment: Scott, can you share your `TrailItem` code and `propTypes` definition since that is where the prop warning is?

Comment: @DrewReese I'm not talking about how JS implements Arrays and Objects. If you define a [proptype](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) as object and provide an array, prop types would throw an error

Comment: @Agney I see what you are saying. It was a bit ambiguous what you were getting at as there are no shared propType definitions in the question. I see you meant the value of `this.props.trails[key]` is an array.

Comment: I changed my "Trails" component to a functional component and destructured the "trails" object. When I `console.log()` I get the array of objects I want, but I still can't figure out how to map over them. I now get an error _"TypeError: trails.map is not a function"_. 

`
const Trails = ({ trails }) => {
  console.log(trails.trails);
  return (
    <div style={trailStyle}>
      {trails.map((trail) => (
        <TrailItem key={trail.id} trail={trail} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
`

Comment: @Agney Thank you, that got rid of the warning. I still need to somehow get the `.map()` to populate a list of `<TrailItem/>.

Comment: @DrewReese I think I'm close here. I added `console.log(trails.trails)` and I finally get the array of objects I want in the browser console. Now I just need to figure out how to `.map()` over that without getting an error. When I try, I get _trails.map() is not a function_

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting everyone. I don't know how to do multi-line code in these comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solved it!** Granted, I may not have been clear in my original question, but I figured out why I couldn't get access to the data object from the API.

I needed to step into the object one more time upon receiving the response in my App component:
`this.setState({ trails: res.data.trails });`

Once I did that, in my Trails component I needed `Object.key()` to make turn the "trails" prop into an array so I could `.map()` over it.

And finally, the "tricky" part was that I needed to use each "key" as the index for each "trail" prop I was trying to pass to `<TrailItem />`:

```
{Object.keys(trails).map((key) => (
    <TrailItem key={key} trail={trails[key]} />
))}
```

Comment: An improvement could be `Object.entries(trails).map(([key, trail]) => (<TrailItem key={key} trail={trail} />))`. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Inside you App render method put this at the start:

```js
if (!this.state.trails.length) {
  return <div>Loading...</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give `trails` a default or initial value of an empty array so the map function can be invoked. By using an empty array the component will map over an the empty array and return an empty array to render.

Default Value:

```
const Trails = ({ trails }) => {
  console.log(trails.trails);
  return (
    <div style={trailStyle}>
      {trails.map(trail => <TrailItem key={trail.id} trail={trail} />)} 
    </div>
  );
};

TrailItem.propTypes = {
  trail: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};
TrailItem.defaultValue = {
  trail: [],
};
```

Initial Value:

```
const Trails = ({ trails = [] }) => {
  console.log(trails.trails);
  return (
    <div style={trailStyle}>
      {trails.map(trail => <TrailItem key={trail.id} trail={trail} />)} 
    </div>
  );
};

TrailItem.propTypes = {
  trail: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};
```

**Note:** This won't fix passing a prop of the incorrect type, but the prop validation react does will. It sounds like you got that bit sorted out though.

Comment: Thank you! This solved all the PropType warnings I was having.